# What does the tensorflow.python.eager.tape do in the implementation of tf.contrib.eager.custom_gradient?

Tags: tensorflow

I am going through TensorFlow Eager Execution from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/g3doc/guide.md) and find it difficult to understand the customizing gradients part.

```
@tfe.custom_gradient
def logexp(x):
    e = tf.exp(x)
    def grad(dy):
        return dy * (1 - 1/(1 + e))
    return tf.log(1 + e), grad
```

First, it is difficult to make sense what does dy do in the gradient function.

When I read the implementation of tf.contrib.eager.custom_gradient.
I can't really make sense the working mechanism behind tape. Following is the code I borrow from the implementation of tf.contrib.eager.custom_gradient. Can anybody explain what does tape do here?

```
from tensorflow.python.eager import tape
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_array_ops
from tensorflow.python.util import nest
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as tf_ops

def my_custom_gradient(f):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        for x in args:
            print('args {0}'.format(x))
        input_tensors = [tf_ops.convert_to_tensor(x) for x in args]

        with tape.stop_recording():
            result, grad_fn = f(*args, **kwargs)
            flat_result = nest.flatten(result)
            flat_result = [gen_array_ops.identity(x) for x in flat_result]

        def actual_grad_fn(*outputs):
            print(*outputs)
            return nest.flatten(grad_fn(*outputs))

       tape.record_operation(
            f.__name__, # the name of f, in this case logexp
            flat_result,
            input_tensors,
            actual_grad_fn) # backward_function
       flat_result = list(flat_result)
       return nest.pack_sequence_as(result, flat_result)
return decorated
```

Even though I found the implementation of tape from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/eager/tape.py). But I can't really get much out of it due the poor documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer each sub-question separately:

**Re: what is `dy`**: Primary use case for gradient functions is during back propagation. During back propagation, the gradient for each op, must take the gradient(s) of its output(s) and produce the gradient(s) of its input(s). This is effectively the consequence of chain rule from calculus. For simple ops, the final gradient is just multiplication of `dy` with the op's gradient (again from chain rule). In this case, you can see `dy * (1 - 1/(1 + e))`.

**Re: `custom_gradient` is complicated**: Yes, it is. The public API for gradient tapes is [`tfe.GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/GradientTape), which should be much easier to understand and work with. You can find simple examples in its spec and its [tests](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/016a79b371061e060ad85b0dbac4aa27d07f0239/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop_test.py#L374). A more complex "real world" example can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/016a79b371061e060ad85b0dbac4aa27d07f0239/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/gan/mnist.py#L230). If its basic workings are not clear, please ask specific questions. Also, we will soon publish a more detailed guide for working with gradients when executing eagerly.

The `tape` that is used to implement `custom_gradient` and `GradientTape` is a low level concept that wraps some C++ code. End users should not care about it (it is not exposed in the `tfe` namespace). It is used to build a "tape" of executed operations. Tape is similar to but simpler than regular TF graphs. It allows one to compute gradients between two tensors it recorded.